# What is the purpose of trailing lambda syntax (Kotlin)?

Tags: lambda, kotlin, fold

[Passing a lambda to the last parameter](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#passing-a-lambda-to-the-last-parameter)

> In Kotlin, there is a convention that if the last parameter of a
>   function accepts a function, a lambda expression that is passed as the
>   corresponding argument can be placed outside the parentheses:
>
> ```
> val product = items.fold(1) { acc, e -> acc * e }
> ```

What is the purpose of this syntax?

Comment: Hint: Have you looked at the function definition of `fold` or understand what it does?

Comment: @cricket_007 I don't think this question has anything to do with how the code works but rather the motivation for the syntax. vkelman, take a look at https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/type-safe-builders.html for some Kotlin code that makes extensive use of the ability to place the lambda outside of the parentheses to create a (in my opinion) very nice dsl.

Comment: @SpencerPark While, yes, the blocks also work for DSL's, I am not sure that is what the question is about. With regards to `fold()` explicitly, the second argument is  a function `(acc: R, nextElement: T) -> R` - https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html

Comment: @cricket_007 The example was taken word for word from the referenced documentation but the question is "What is the purpose of this syntax?". It looks like a question about language design but we will have to let vkelman clear that up.

Comment: Well, the "purpose" is that it matches the method API. It's not the only way to write it, though. It could also be written as `items.fold(1, { ... })`, as shown in that last link

Comment: Well, I explicitly asked what is the purpose of this (confusing to me) syntax. I didn't  ask what fold is doing. The answer I got - it allows for DSL.
In my opinion, often those syntactic sugar things intended to prettify a language actually make code harder to understand.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This syntax gives Kotlin great DSL capabilities, it makes functions look like language constructions. For example:

```
with(car) {
   startUp()
   goToDestination()
}
```

Here `with` looks like it is language construction, whereas it is a simple function, receiving lambda as the last parameter.

And this leads to such elegant things like [Kotlin HTML DSL](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/type-safe-builders.html)

Comment: How is a Domain Specific Language useful in kotlin?  Why not just use the domain specific language instead if you're writing for a specific domain?

Comment: @SMBiggs Most DSLs are implemented in traditional languages because it's generally not worthwhile to create an entire language just for a DSL. Some languages are more suited to DSLs than others, for example Groovy (the standard Gradle DSL is implemented in Groovy, although more recently you can also use Kotlin, and popular CI DSL such as Jenkins Job DSL is implemented in Groovy). There are also DSLs in Java such as Mockito for testing, although Java as a language is perhaps less suited to DSLs.